# Blog post about computational topology

Tags: discussion, blog

Can I make a blog post to resurrect the [cstheory blog](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/) about computational topology? The blog post would be about decision problems in knot theory specifically the unknotting problem and knot recognition.

I would talk about the following

1. History of the unknotting problem
2. Why it is decidable
3. Current approaches
4. Implications of solution

Comment: That's a great idea.

Comment: I think the editors for the blog are: [Joe](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/204/joe-fitzsimons) and [Aarron](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/30/aaron-sterling). I don't know if they are still interested in be editors. I would suggest that you send them an email. If they are not interested then we may need to find new editors for the blog.

Comment: @Kaveh Both of them aren't editors anymore. I am willing to be an editor.

Comment: You should contact the moderators (in particular Suresh). I don't recall the process through which we decided to make Joe and Aarron our blog editors last time. I personally think @Artem would be a more suitable editor as he is an elected community mod and very experienced blogger.

Comment: @Kaveh the last time I submitted an article both people rejected it because it was too simple.

Comment: huh, who rejected it? the community blog has not been updated in several years. knowledgeable volunteers should not be turned away. "something is better than nothing." also standards/ criteria/ rigor/ scope/ ambition etc for the blog do not necessarily need to be the same as the main site. the knot problem is research level in general. note as admitted by mgt (in a chat room) that stackexchange has a general problem with dormant blogs & some lack of enthusiasm/ engagement for the community blogging feature.

Comment: @Vzn it was when the blog was still in its infancy. I realize now that it was the right decision

Comment: @kaveh I haven't received a response from Artem. I will try suresh

Comment: @kaveh I will try to contact suresh now.